# How to save JSON to table storage in the azure without deserialization?

Tags: json, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage

I have a message coming to me from the outside world in JSON format. I know for sure what is going to be partition key and row key in the JSON but I don't want to deserialize all properties of that object. How can I save this string using Table API SDK available?

E.g. that is my input string:

```
{
"name":"John Doe",
"age":38,
"country":"USA",
"phone_number":"+123456789",
"current_balance":100500,
"subscribed":false
}
```

For that particular example, I would like to define the name as a row key and country as a partition key. In the same time, I don't want to perform deserialization of the whole entity but store all the data available. However, using [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table) package I found no way to just dump this data directly to the table. What is a preferable option to do that?

Comment: If you don't want to deserialise, maybe consider using blob instead of table storage

Comment: Furthermore: if you don't want to deserialize, how are you going to get the `name` and `country` values to be used as RowKey and PartitionKey? What language are you using? You _could_ just store the entire JSON as a third column like `payload` (next to RowKey and PartitionKey)

Comment: With Table Storage this isn't possible. With the Cosmos DB SQL API v3 .NET SDK, there is a stream option in the works which will allow already serialized payloads to be passed in.